# C# XML - Collapse XML properties into a list/array

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-serialization

I'm trying to serialize an XML file returned from a SOAP API service. The issue is that they have defined an array of objects as such:

```
<soap_xml>
    ...
    <item __array="true">
        <some_property>text here<some_property/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <some_property>text here<some_property/>
    </item>
    ...
</soap_xml>
```

Is there anyway to use the XmlSerializer to condense this down into an array when deserializing this XML file, or will I have to process the entire XML file manually. I'm not keen on having to process the XML manually, since it has over 100 different properties/fields, but if there is no other solution, then I'll have to use a XMLReader and write a custom serializer.

Also, asking the API provider to change the format of the returned XML is out of the question.

Comment: Just to clarify, is this XML defined by the wsdl, or is it just returned as a string?

Comment: Returned as a string. There is no WSDL or schema for this API.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define a class that follows the schema of the XML file - do you have a schema from the API provider?  If so, you could use xsd.exe to generate a class file that can load it.

Alternatively, you'll need to annotate your own class with the appropriate XML attributes that follows the format.

Comment: No, there is no schema from the provider. I only have a few sample xml documents to work from, as well as a list of all of the children from the root node, and several other notes including this: "If attribute __array=”true” is present it indicates that it shall be an array of items (even if it’s just one item present)"

Also, my class does have the correct XML attributes, the only issue is that the "list" element gets overwritten by the contents of the last "list" node, and I need to condense all the list nodes into either an array or a list.